Movie with blond woman possibly selling drugs, ODs
Sure it's from the UK 2000s but can only remember 1 scene.
Sexy youngish blonde women with possibly russian accent, make up and big hoop earring sitting at a bar and a guy comes in (undercover cop) and chats with her. He asks her if she knows the size of a $50 or $100 bill and the weight etc. and then says it's curious how a bag of whatever drugs she's dealing is worth more!
He makes her be quiet by telling her it wouldn't be good for business if a cop was sniffing around. Next she goes to her boyfriend's/f*** buddy's hotel with her daughter where he tells her to leave, he doesn't love her etc. The woman leaves crying and overdoses where she ends up in the hospital. The police go there and blackmail her for her boyfriend's whereabouts or her daughter will be taken from her.

You're talking about The Town from 2010 with Ben Affleck (who also directed). In the first scene you've described, the blonde is Krista (Blake Lively) sporting a heavy Boston accent and wearing big hoop earrings. She sits at a bar and Frawley, an FBI agent (John Hamm), tells her about the size and weight of a $20 bill and how it's not worth its own weight in value like the drugs in her bag. Here's the scene:



And later, as quoted from TheMovieSpoiler:

Doug plans the job from a nearby hotel room. Krista arrives, unexpectedly, with her daughter. She begs Doug to take her with him wherever he's going. Doug kicks her out, with her daughter, telling her that the kid isn't his. Krista leaves in a huff, and strung out on drugs, crashes her car with the kid in the backseat. She's taken to the hospital where she has her stomach pumped, and is visited by Agent Frawley. Frawley promises to provide her now foster-child a better life if Krista tells him the location of the next job. She tells him.

Here's the trailer.
